# trying to understand ms excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im learning how to write excel formulas and a guy from work gave me a spreadsheet of his to learn in my spare time.

Ive looked up alot of information regarding formulas. but I cant quite understand how it appears to have 2-questions which is in a string.

Is it possible for someone to explain how this syntax works ?

```
=-1*(E8*'2-questions'!$P$9/10)
```

Comment: Are you asking what '2-questions' means in the context of this formula? If so, it is the name of the worksheet for P9.

Answer (score 1):

Range references.

If a formula includes a range address all by itself, that address is a reference to that range on the same worksheet as the formula:

```
=P9
```

But to reference the same range on another worksheet in the same workbook, the address is prefixed by the name of the other sheet along with an exclamation point:

```
=Sheet2!P9
```

And if the name of the other worksheet includes any space characters, then the name must be surrounded by single quotes:

```
='2-questions'!P9
```

.

The range reference syntax can also have an additional prefix for the name of the workbook in square brackets, which is required if the reference is to a range in another workbook:

```
=[Book2]'2-questions'!P9
```

Comment: Also note that column name viz. P and row number viz. 9 both are prefixed with $ sign. This is called absolute reference. Because of this cell P9 shall be referred absolutely by the cell where this formula is placed. In simple words if this formula were to be in a cell say X10 then the formula mentioned would be treated as =-1*(E8*'2-questions'!$pP$9/10). And if contents of X10 (formula in question) were copied to a cell say X11 then it would be treated as =-1*(E9*'2-questions'!$P$9/10). That means cell P9 will be referred absolutely in the calling cell.

Comment: @Lalu Why did you write this here?

Comment: 'cause this is just an add on to a nice answer of yours.

Comment: @Lalu I avoided the absolute vs relative referencing discussion in order to keep the answer focused on the question.

Comment: @user125264 Did this answer your question?